# Python - How to display answer's in a table list at the end of a program?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, if-statement

I have an assignment which requires the user to input a number (>1), an operation (+, -, *). At the end of the program it takes the two and they are used in conjunction with an ascending table of numbers from 1 to 10. The only issue i'm having is figuring out how to get it to show the answer after the '='.

If I could get some help, that would be great. I've literally spent a couple of hours trying to figure out this little thing and am just stumped.

```
 # User inputs a #
num1 = int(input("Enter a numuber of 1 or greater: "))
while (num1 < 1):
     num1 = int(input("Error! Number too small, try again!: "))

if (num1 >= 1):
     print("Correct!\n")     

# Program shows a list up to the value entered by the user
print("Counting from 0 to", str(num1) + ": ")

for i in range(0, num1 + 1, 1):
     print(i, end = "   ")
print()

# User chooses which math operation to use
usrIp = input("\nChoose a math operation (+, -, *): ")

while (usrIp != '+') and (usrIp != '-') and (usrIp != '*'):
     usrIp = input("\nError! Try again!:")


# User submitted value is added to a number increasing by 1 for each line

print("\nTable for", num1, "using", usrIp, ":")
if (usrIp == '+') or (usrIp == '-') or (usrIp == '*'):
    for i in range(1, 11, 1):
        if (usrIp == '+'):
            print(num1, usrIp, i, '=')
        if (usrIp == '*'):
            print(num1, usrIp, i, '=')
        if (usrIp == '-'):
            print(num1, usrIp, i, '=')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program looks good! It's great that you've separated the program into smaller problems, this will help you a lot when your problems become more complex.

Since this is an assignment, I will give you a hint on how to proceed:

```
if (usrIp == '+'):
    answer = 
    print(num1, usrIp, i, '=', answer)
```

You should be able to figure out what to do with that and replicate it in the other if statements.

Welcome to Stack Overflow and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks so much, It's nice to hear from someone else that I'm off to a good start!                                                                                                                 I'll figure it out from here, thanks. I look forward to being involved!

Comment: @CameronRogozinsky Glad I could help. If this answer helped you, you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/252544) and be rewarded with 2 rep points :)